# iOS: Using constants from new SDK in old iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I want to use a constant (kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake from ImageIO framework). This constant is available starting with iOS 6. When I use this constant and run the project on an iOS 5 device it crashes with:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake
```

It sufficies to include the constant anywhere in the project, even if the code is not executed, to make the app crash. So it does not help to check the iOS version during runtime.

How can I include this constant in my project, so that I can use it on iOS 6 devices without crashing the app on iOS 5?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the ImageIO framework (or a documentation bug) to me.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005103-CH3g-SW4), `kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake` is available in iOS 4.3 and later.

According to

```
IMAGEIO_EXTERN const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake  IMAGEIO_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_5_0);
```

in `CGImageProperties.h`, it is available in iOS 5.0 and later.

But if you inspect the symbols of the ImageIO framework with

```
$ nm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO | grep kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake

0026a59c s _kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake
```

the lowercase "s" shows that the symbol is local, not exported.

As a workaround, you can add

```
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake = CFSTR("LensMake");
```

somewhere in your app, then it works on iOS 5 and 6.